# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: y + height must be <= bitmap.height()

Tags: android, bitmap

I am trying to build this application where I need to divide the given bitmap image into smaller chunks and for this, I am using the following code snippet.

```
PuzzleBoard(Bitmap bitmap, int parentWidth) {
    tiles=new ArrayList<>();
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, parentWidth, parentWidth, true);
    int chunkSize=parentWidth/NUM_TILES;
    int cnt=0;
    for(int i=0;i<NUM_TILES;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<NUM_TILES;i++){
             if((cnt)<NUM_TILES*NUM_TILES-1){
                   Bitmap tile= Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap,j*chunkSize,i*chunkSize,chunkSize,chunkSize);
                   PuzzleTile t=new PuzzleTile(tile,cnt);
                   tiles.add(t);
             }
             cnt++;
        }
    }
}
```

But, my application crashed when i ran the code on my device. When I saw the logcat I got this

```
07-12 14:33:36.747 21428-21428/com.google.engedu.puzzle8 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.google.engedu.puzzle8, PID: 21428
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {com.google.engedu.puzzle8/com.google.engedu.puzzle8.PuzzleActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: y + height must be <= bitmap.height()
       at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3365)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3408)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: y + height must be <= bitmap.height()
       at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:668)
       at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:632)
       at com.google.engedu.puzzle8.PuzzleBoard.<init>(PuzzleBoard.java:51)
       at com.google.engedu.puzzle8.PuzzleBoardView.initialize(PuzzleBoardView.java:29)
       at com.google.engedu.puzzle8.PuzzleActivity.onActivityResult(PuzzleActivity.java:68)
       at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5430)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3361)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3408) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:135) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

After trying a bit to resolve the issue, I set the filter parameter of Bitmap.createScaledBitmap() to "false" and then my application is running fine. But, I didn't understand the logic behind it. Can someone explain me why this happened ?

EDITS:
   The parentWidth value is 432. The constructor is called from another class method initialize()

```
public void initialize(Bitmap imageBitmap) {
    int width = getWidth();
    puzzleBoard = new PuzzleBoard(imageBitmap, width);
}
```

Comment: Where to you call the constructor of PuzzleBoard? Have you checked what is the value of parentWidth when you call the constructor?

Comment: that looks wrong ( i++ instead of j++ ) : for(int j=0;j<NUM_TILES;i++) - but this might not be your problem - you try to cut something from outside an image - on a second thought this might be your problem - providing this as an answer

Comment: Oh shoot!! I made a blunder and didn't realize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a typo here:

```
for(int i=0;i<NUM_TILES;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<NUM_TILES;i++){
```

replace the second i++ with j++

btw: i and j are really bad variable names for this - better would be x and y - then you might have seen this your self ..